# New ogg files in 17.10 won't play

Tags: rhythmbox, clementine, ogg-vorbis, audio-player

I have recently ripped two CDs in 17.10. One using Sound Juicer the other Audex. None of the files produced will play in Rhythmbox, Clementine or Amorak, despite the fact that they will play on other devices-namely a Macbook in Nightingale.
Does anyone have any idea why this might be?

Comment: I should add that I have many other ogg files from previous Ubuntu installs which play perfectly on this set up, it is just those that have been recently added that are giving trouble.

Comment: Just observed that these same files play OK in Ocenaudio on the same machine, but not in Rhythmbox or Clementine as i said above.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add details, instead of using comments

Comment: When you say they won't play, what do you mean exactly? Does the music player fail to open them? or does it open them but produce no sound? If there are any error messages, please add them verbatim to the question.

Comment: Thank you for you your responses!
Subsequently I re encoded these files from the CD and found they played fine, so I assumed there was some error on the encode. Thinking about it now however, that does not quite make sense, as the files played on other devices.
The files would appear in the library of Rhythmbox or Clementine but then would refuse to play, no sound and playback would just stop with no error message. I no longer have the files so sadly can't add much more detail. Thank you